# format lines using Shell scripts

Tags: shell, format, line

I have a list of shell scripts (that end with .sh) in a folder and I am trying to make a list of them, and the list should have two script names (separated by a space) in each line. I wrote the following script, but it does not work without showing any errors. I was hoping to get some help here:

```
file1=""

for file in $(ls ./*.sh); do

   i=1
   file1="$file1$file "

   if [ $i -lt 3 ]; then
      i=$(( i++ ))
      continue
   fi

    echo "file1 is $file1"           # expected $file1 is: scriptName1.sh scriptName2.sh
    echo $file1 >> ScriptList.txt    # save the two file names in the text file 
    file1=""
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get tab separated output:

```
  ls *.sh | paste - -
```

Comment: +1 for paste, but you shouldn't use `ls`, use `printf "%s\n" *.sh | paste - -`

Comment: is there a way to get "space" separated output? thanks

Comment: How does printf help?  I like the idea of doing `printf "%25s\n" *sh` to help with alignment, but without a width specifier it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: To change the delimiter to space, use `paste -d ' ' - -`

Answer (score 2):

The [`pr`](http://man.cx/pr) utility is handy for columnizing as well. It can split the data "vertically":

```
$ seq 10 | pr -2 -T -s" "
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

or "horizontally"

```
$ seq 10 | pr -2 -T -s" " -a
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to set `i=1` everytime in your loop.

Try

```
ls -1 | while read a;
do 
    if [ -z $save ]; then
        save="$a"
    else
        echo "$save $a"
        save=""
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that `-1` is automatically enabled when the output of `ls`  is piped or redirected. Compare `ls` with `ls | cat`

Comment: However, `ls > /dev/tty` will produce columns  :)